# SQL Select same row (amount) times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2005

```
CAR       |  AMOUNT
---------------------
Ford      | 5
---------------------
Peugeot   | 7
---------------------
```

This is my Table, I want to see on my result screen 5 times "Ford" and 7 times "Peugeot"

Comment: Show us the exact output you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (10) rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns 
  ORDER BY [object_id]
)
--select * from x
SELECT car,AMOUNT
FROM x
CROSS JOIN #table2 AS d
WHERE x.rn <= d.AMOUNT
ORDER BY d.AMOUNT;
```

output

```
car AMOUNT
Ford    5
Ford    5
Ford    5
Ford    5
Ford    5
Peugeot 7
Peugeot 7
Peugeot 7
Peugeot 7
Peugeot 7
Peugeot 7
Peugeot 7
```